Suddenly I got undefined python version error in jupyter notebook (vscode)
Suddenly, my vscode have an undefined kernel error.
I can run my code, but when I try to run my code that undefined kernel error message comes out and link to here (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/wiki/Using-unsupported-Python-Environments)
I think my python version is okay, because I can run my python in terminal.
Why does this error come up?
Undefined Python Version Error:

Python in Terminal:

I've search theses type of error but I can not seem to find any solution for this error

Have you set the Python interpreter correctly? Press Ctrl + Shift + P (or Cmd + Shift + P on macOS) to open the Command Palette. Type Python select interpreter and press Enter.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-kernel-management

same error... if you choose a kernel, it will turn out to be undefined...

Select your python interpreter then choose your jupyter kernel. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks#_create-or-open-a-jupyter-notebook

I just reset vscode and make new kernel then the existing kernel became normal state,,
So i guess it is not selecting python interpreter error, I think it was a temporary problem with vscode.

Hi Gumraze, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! you could click '✔' to mark it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See also can I answer my own question..
, Just a reminder :)

This issue could be caused by the kernel mismatch with python version. Your python version is 3.11.7, you can select command Python select interpreter look for your python interpreter and select the interpreter that matches. You can learn more about the Jupyter interpreter in the document.
